# Object being squished when using object offset in array modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to make treads around a tire by applying an *Array Modifier* and using the *Object Offset*, but when I select object offset the tire tread it creates is squished in the X axis.

The offset object I am using is an empty plain axes, I've tried offsetting it to other objects and the same thing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, you just have to make sure that the scale of the object you're using as your object offset is the same as the object your applying the modifier to is the same.