# Object offset of array modifier acting weird

Tags: modeling

When I am adding object offset to an array modifier he is not using original sizes instead he is transform my object and then add it.

[image]

Comment: I found it!
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120900/object-being-squished-when-using-object-offset-in-array-modifier

Comment: apply the scale of both your object and the array offset object. Also, as you're using an offset object, are you sure you want to keep the relative offset?

Comment: Ok, how to close question?

Comment: what is the good answer? you can answer to yourself...